# Wordpress search post using unicode

Tags: search, rest-api

I'm working with wordpress rest api
I need to searching WP posts with unicode character
example searching on my site:

```
https://example.net/?s=ngoại+tình
```

The results is OK
The I applied to my api : 
API URL :

```
https://example.net/wp-json/v1/search?keyword=ngoại+tình
```

Code:

```
$arrayPostFilter = array (
        "orderby" => "publish_date",
        "s" => $_GET['keyword'], 
        "posts_per_page" => 20,     
        'numberposts'=>-1,
        "paged" => $paged
    );
```

It's have no result, no posts found

Do I have to setting anything relate to Unicode for query filter?

Comment: Is there any specific reasons you're still using the old REST API version? And with version 2, you'd simply make requests to `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=keyword`, but remove the `"s" => $_GET['keyword']` in your code.

Comment: v1/search is my custom api. The problem is that I can not search with keyword unicode

Comment: Yes, I did think of that. So try using `sanitize_text_field( $_GET['keyword'] )` ?

Comment: Oh, you save my day. It's work with `sanitize_text_field`. Thank you very much @SallyCJ

Comment: You're welcome & merry Christmas!